# Returning Fields of an excel xml file with PHP or jquery

Tags: php, xml, excel, jquery

I have created and excel xml file that has three cols First Name, Surname and Email.  New information is added to the file but how can i call back the rows to show the information one under each other like in excel by using php or jquery (ajax) to do this?

construction is

```
<Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s21"><Data ss:Type="String">First Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s21"><Data ss:Type="String">Surname</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s21"><Data ss:Type="String">Email Address</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NAME1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SURNAME1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22" ss:HRef="mailto:EMAIL1"><Data
      ss:Type="String">EMAIL1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
      <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NAME2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SURNAME2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22" ss:HRef="mailto:EMAIL2"><Data
      ss:Type="String">EMAIL2</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
      <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NAME3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SURNAME3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22" ss:HRef="mailto:EMAIL3"><Data
      ss:Type="String">EMAIL3</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

RESULT:

FIRST NAME    SURNAME     EMAIL
NAME1         SURNAME1    EMAIL1
NAME2         SURNAME2    EMAIL2

ETC.
```

Comment: If you are talking about "in php or jquery" you probably have not understood enough of your problem to solve it. PHP nearly always runs on your server before a page is sent to the client; jquery is Javascript, which nearly always runs on a client after PHP (or whateve) has finished creating the page and sent it to the client. Where do you want this to be happening? What is the trigger for it?

Comment: Hi Colin i meant using php or jquery ajax to get the inforation from the xml file stored on the server to show the fields in the html page either using php or jquery to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/